# How to perform heavy task in react native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, multithreading, react-native

Getting some data from a hardware device via bluetooth in every 10 milliseconds. Performing some heavy task like merging data, parsing, building list and setting into state to show data into table and graph.

The issue is UI is freezing while receiving data from bluetooth. Not able to perform touch in UI but data is rendering in UI.

```
BluetoothService.getInstance().monitorRecord((record: Record) => {
// This is a callback calling in every 10 milliseconds

            //setting record into state, setting record into state is taking 100+ milliseconds
            setRecord(record);
            // Preparing suitable data fro graph this is taking 2 milliseconds
            prepareDataFroGraph(record);
            
            //building list of record this will taking 2 milliseconds
            recordData(record);
        }, TransactionId.MONITOR_RECORD)
```

Comment: I tried async function and RxJs observable but could not resolved the issue

Comment: what is inside setRecord?

Comment: setRecord is a setState method for record eg. const [record, setRecord] = useState<Record>();

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you use setState continuously and because of that ui rerender which results max exceed, UI Freezes and app closes. so please check this

Comment: Yes this is because of setState continuously calling in every 10 milliseconds. I need to render data into a graph and table

Comment: maybe you can consider handling records in batches, and call setState less. Also there is a lot of optimization technics for react that you can look at, like `memo` and `useMemo`